# PHP autoloader not working with namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload

Its the first time working with an autoloader and getting some errors. 
The structure is as follows:

- AnimalShop (root)

  - classes

    - Shop.php
  - index.php

I have the following simple code

**Index.php**

```
<?php

spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) 
{
    include $class_name . '.php';
});

echo "<h1>PETs SHOP</h1>";

// Create a shop

$shop = new Shop();
```

Shop is a simple class

```
<?php

namespace PHPAdvanced\AnimalShop\classes;

/*
 * Pet shop
 */

    class Shop
    {

        /**
         * @var Pets[] pets
         */
        private $pets = [];

        public function addPetsToArray(Pets $pet)
        {
            $this->pets[] = $pet;
        }


        /**
         * Print pets naam
         */
        public function printPets()
        {
            foreach($this->pets as $pet)
            {
                echo "<p>" . $pet->getPetNaam() . "</p>";
            }
        }
    }
```

When i run index.php i get the following errors:

Warning: include(Shop.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/phpadvancedCourse/AnimalShop/index.php on line 4

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Shop.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:') in /var/www/phpadvancedCourse/AnimalShop/index.php on line 4

Comment: is `shop.php` located in `/var/www/phpadvancedCourse/AnimalShop/` ?

Comment: nvm i see it in your question..

Comment: `include 'classes/' . $class_name . '.php';`

Comment: just as a side note this is kind of a weird way to use namespaces and an autoloader.  you should look into `PSR-0` and `PSR-4`

Answer (score 0):

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) 
{
    include realpath(dirname(__FILE__))."/classes/".$class_name . '.php';
});
```

your path is wrong.. try this..

Comment: Above code not working the error that i get is:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Shop' not found in /var/www/phpadvancedCourse/AnimalShop/index.php on line 12

Error: Class 'Shop' not found in /var/www/phpadvancedCourse/AnimalShop/index.php on line 12

Comment: if that's the error you got then you didn't use my code. why don't you actually try the code i gave you before saying it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem i have used PSR-4 autoloading through composer with the following structure and code.

**Structure**

- AnimalShop (root)

  - index.php
  - App (Folder)

    - Behavior (Folder)

      - WalkBehavior.php (interface)
    - Pets(Folder)

      - Cat.php
      - Dog.php
      - Fish.php
      - Pets.php (abstract class)
    - Shop(Folder)

      - PetShop.php

**Composer.json**

```
{
    "autoload" : {
        "psr-4" : {
            "App\\" : "App"
        }
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

// Autoload
require "vendor/autoload.php";

use App\Shop\PetShop;
use App\Pets\Dog;
use App\Pets\Fish;
use App\Pets\Cat;

echo "<h1>PETs SHOP</h1>";

// Create a shop
$shop = new PetShop();

$shop->addPetsToArray(new Dog("Yuki"));
$shop->addPetsToArray(new Fish("BLubie"));
$shop->addPetsToArray(new Cat("Cattie"));

$shop->printPets();
```

Example of Petshop and Dog

```
<?php

namespace App\Shop;

use App\Pets\Pets;

/*
 * Pet shop
 */

class PetShop
{

    /**
     * @var Pets[] pets
     */
    private $pets = [];

    public function addPetsToArray(Pets $pet)
    {
        $this->pets[] = $pet;
    }


    /**
     * Print pets naam
     */
    public function printPets()
    {
        foreach($this->pets as $pet)
        {
            echo "<p>" . $pet->getPetNaam() . "</p>";
        }
    }
}
```

DOG

```
<?php
namespace App\Pets;

/**
 * Class Dog
 */
class Dog extends Pets
{
    /**
     * Dog constructor.
     *
     * @param $name
     */
    public function __construct(string $name)
    {
        parent::__construct($name);
    }

    public function walk() : string
    {
        return "Dog is walking";
    }
}
```